# Ensuring at least one ingress-nginx per kubernetes node

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to write an autoscaling configuration for ingress-nginx, deployed via helm chart.

my goals are:

- 3 minimum replicas (because I have 3 nodes minimum)
- ensure only one nginx per node, but:
- be elastic, if autoscale says we need 4 nginx allow for a node in the cluster to have 2
- if a fourth node gets added, ensure a new nginx gets spawned

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L326
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L343
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L256

I tried playing with the below settings and a combination of them but there's always something off, for example right now I have a fourth nginx that want to spawn for some reason and it can't because of the antiaffinity rule.

Can anyone share some ideas how to achieve that?

- always one nginx per node, if a new node gets created, a new nginx gets created
- preserve autoscaling, if hpa wants to spawn a fourth nginx on a 3 node cluster it should be free to do so

```yaml
      replicaCount: 3
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
                operator: In
                values:
                - ingress-nginx
              - key: app.kubernetes.io/instance
                operator: In
                values:
                - ingress-nginx
              - key: app.kubernetes.io/component
                operator: In
                values:
                - controller
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"

      topologySpreadConstraints:
        - maxSkew: 1
          topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
          whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
          labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx

      autoscaling:
        enabled: true
        minReplicas: 3
        maxReplicas: 6
        targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 75
        targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 100
```

Comment: If you need only one nginx instance per node, wouldn't it be easier to deploy it as [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) ?

Comment: is it possibile to deploy as daemonset via the helm chart?

Comment: just found out https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L174

Comment: thanks for the hint, seems working, if you wanna put an official reply I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need only one nginx instance per node, wouldn't it be easier to deploy it as [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) ?

As you can read in the official docs:

> A *DaemonSet* ensures that all (or some) Nodes run a copy of a Pod. As
> nodes are added to the cluster, Pods are added to them. As nodes are
> removed from the cluster, those Pods are garbage collected. Deleting a
> DaemonSet will clean up the Pods it created.

And this seems like the right solution in your use case.

As you rightly suggested in your comment, [nginx-ingress official helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx) can be deployed both as a `Deployment` or as a `DaemonSet`. It can be done [by adjusting its `values.yaml` file](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L174).

Comment: I find it worth mentioning that switching between the two modes works without having to uninstall anything first.